# How are pi-orbitals delocalized in a porphyrin chain?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

According to [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S1468-6996(03)00061-5), the orbitals appear delocalized mostly from left to right, and only along 1-2 units of the chain.

Is that really the case? If so,

1. Why is the delocalization only along 1-2 units of the chain and not throughout the chain?
2. Why is there no delocalization in the up-down direction?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing are *molecular orbitals* which, by definition, extend across the entire molecule, restricted only by inherent symmetry. It is important to note and is not clearly visible in your image that you are looking at a $\ce{H2-Fe-Zn-H2}$ system, i.e. from one side to the other the centres of the porphyrin system contain two hydrogens, an iron ion, a zinc ion and another two hydrogens. Replace the zinc with iron or vice-versa and you would get an axis of symmetry with molecular orbitals that are either perfectly symmetric or perfectly antisymmetric to this axis of symmetry.

As it is drawn, the molecule is $C_\sigma$, i.e. there is a single plain of symmetry along the plain of the molecule. All orbitals must be symmetric or antisymmetric to this plain, and since we are looking at a $\unicode[Times]{x3C0}$-system, it will be antisymmetric.

**All the rest is the result of a calculation!** So we cannot really answer why, all we can say is ‘because that is what maths gives us’. But we can slightly rationalise it. First, there *is* a difference between the top and the bottom, it is just not as easily visible. This is because the only difference between the top and the bottom is ‘where exactly are the two hydrogens and the double bonds?’ Second, the two ions are clearly different ones with different electronegativities that create entirely different environments. Therefore, it is understandable that one orbital is centred more around one of the two ions and the other around the other. And third, the LUMO$+1$ is clearly delocalised across the entire molecule.

Comment: Why do you say that the LUMO+1 is delocalized across the entire molecule if in the drawing it appears discontinuous?

Comment: @Sparkler Don’t confuse a nodal plain where the wave changes phase with a discontinuity.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that really the case?

That is, in fact, difficult to say on the basis of the study you referenced, since I would not blindly trust the Hartree-Fock results presented there. Try to search for more recent studies done at a higher (DFT or MP2) level of theory.<sup>1</sup>

But if, for the sake of argument, we pretend for a moment that HF picture presented in the study is qualitatively right, I have to say: you ask the wrong questions! Because, the only right answer to both of your "Why?" questions is: "Because that what's calculations tell us!" We are doing calculations to explain what's going on out there, so you already have the answers. If you want to go further than that, then your probably looking for one of two things:

- You either want to go deeper and ask "Why nature works this way?" But this is not a deep scientific question, it is simply not a scientific one at all. Such questions are beyond science, it's a metaphysics already, or philosophy, if you will.
- Or you want to go in the opposite direction looking for some simple rationalization of the orbital picture in the usual chemical terms (such as, for instance, resonance, hyperconjugation, steric effects, etc.) I suspects this is also impossible in this case, since all these (over)simplified chemical models usually work well only in the simplest cases. That is, in fact, why chemist do calculations in the first place.

---

1) About a decade ago (when the paper you quote was published) DFT/MP2 calculations of such relatively big molecules were basically out-of-reach, but with all the progress in RI-DFT/RI-MP2 methods they could be more or less routinely done these days.

Comment: Can you please add a few links you'd recommend reading about the theories you mentioned? (RI-DFT/RI-MP2)

Comment: @Sparkler [RI-MP2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(93)87156-W), [RI-DFT](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(95)00621-A).